# Combining local result with possible (timeout/error) async web result

Tags: system.reactive

I have two methods that both return an IObservable

```
IObservable<Something[]> QueryLocal();
```

and

```
IObservable<Something[]> QueryWeb();
```

QueryLocal is always successful. QueryWeb is susceptible to both a timeout and possible web errors.

I wish to implement a QueryLocalAndWeb() that calls both and combines their results. 
So far I have:

```
IObservable<Something[]> QueryLocalAndWeb()
{
  var a = QueryLocal();
  var b = QueryWeb();
  var plan = a.And(b).Then((x, y) => x.Concat(y).ToArray());
  return Observable.When(plan).Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), a);
}
```

However, I'm not sure that it handles the case where QueryWeb yields an error.
In the future I might have a QueryWeb2() that also needs to be taken into account.

So, how do I combine the results from a number of IObservables ignoring the ones that throw errors (or time out)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `OnErrorResumeNext` should be able to handle this scenario:

**From MSDN:**

> Continues an observable sequence that is terminated normally or by an
>   exception with the next observable sequence.

```
IObservable<Something[]> QueryLocalAndWeb()
{
  var a = QueryLocal();
  var b = QueryWeb().Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
  return Observable.OnErrorResumeNext(b, a);
}
```

You can do concat of array by using Aggregation on the returned observable.
I am assuming that both local and web are cold observable i.e they start producing values only when someone subscribes to them.

Comment: Looks interesting albeit very confusingly named.
What happens if a throws? Does that get propagated?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var plan = a.And(b).Then((x, y) => x.Concat(y.Catch(Observable.Empty<Something[]>()).ToArray());
```

Comment: Is the And satisfied if b throws? Or would it make more sense with a.And(b.Catch(empty)).Then(...

Comment: Hmmm, it probably wouldn't, might be better to put the catch on 'b'